# loading from remote sql database into android activity exception

Tags: php, android, html, mysql, database

I'm trying to import information from an external database into my android app using php, I get the following error, showing that nothing is being imported, I checked 5 times and all the names of the files are correct so I don't know what the problem can be. My table is of the following schema

id zadanie odp_a odp_b odp_c odp_d comment correctanswer

LOGCAT :

```html
   Process: com.example.albert.mathapp, PID: 21659
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.albert.mathapp.MainActivity$LoadAllQuestions.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:78)
            at com.example.albert.mathapp.MainActivity$LoadAllQuestions.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:56)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-26 21:41:45.589  21659-21659/com.example.albert.mathapp E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.albert.mathapp.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42a4ecb8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:436)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:267)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:288)
            at com.example.albert.mathapp.MainActivity$LoadAllQuestions.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:65)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at com.example.albert.mathapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

CODE OF ACTIVITY :

```html
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionlist;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_games = "http://*****/get_all_questions.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_QUESTIONLIST = "questionlist";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_ZADANIE = "zadanie";
    private static final String TAG_ODP_A = "odp_a";
    private static final String TAG_ODP_B = "odp_b";
    private static final String TAG_ODP_C = "odp_c";
    private static final String TAG_ODP_D = "odp_d";
    private static final String TAG_COMMENT = "comment";
    private static final String TAG_CORRECTANSWER = "correctanswer";
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray allquestions = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        questionlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllQuestions().execute();
    }

        class LoadAllQuestions extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading Games. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * getting All products from url
             */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_games, "GET", params);

                // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                Log.d("All Questions: ", json.toString());

                try {
                    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // products found
                        // Getting Array of Games
                        allquestions = json.getJSONArray(TAG_QUESTIONLIST);

                        // looping through All Products
                        for (int i = 0; i < allquestions.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = allquestions.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                            String zadanie = c.getString(TAG_ZADANIE);
                            String odp_a = c.getString(TAG_ODP_A);
                            String odp_b = c.getString(TAG_ODP_B);
                            String odp_c  = c.getString(TAG_ODP_C);
                            String odp_d = c.getString(TAG_ODP_D);
                            String comment = c.getString(TAG_COMMENT);
                            String correctanswer = c.getString(TAG_CORRECTANSWER);
                            Log.d("id",id);
                            Log.d("zadanie",zadanie);


                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                            map.put(TAG_ZADANIE, zadanie);
                            map.put(TAG_ODP_A, odp_a);
                            map.put(TAG_ODP_B, odp_b);
                            map.put(TAG_ODP_C, odp_c);
                            map.put(TAG_ODP_D, odp_d);
                            map.put(TAG_COMMENT,comment);
                            map.put(TAG_CORRECTANSWER,correctanswer);


                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            questionlist.add(map);
                        }

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return "";
            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * *
             */
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread



            }


        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

GET_ALL_QUESTIONS.PHP

```html
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the questions
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connectmaths.php';

// connecting to db
$con = new DB_CONNECT();
$con->connect();

// get all questions from questions table
$result = mysqli_query($con->myconn, "SELECT * FROM `abcd`") or die(mysql_error());


// check for empty result
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // questions node
    $response["questions"] = array();
    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $question = array();
        $question["id"] = $row["id"];
        $question["zadanie"] = $row["zadanie"];
        $question["odp_a"] = $row["odp_a"];
        $question["odp_b"] = $row["odp_b"];
        $question["odp_c"] = $row["odp_c"];
        $question["odp_d"] = $row["odp_d"];
        $question["comment"] = $row["comment"];
        $question["correctanswer"] = $row["correctanswer"]



        // push single question into final response array
        array_push($response["questions"], $question);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no questions found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No questions found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

db_connectmaths.php

```html
<?php

/**
 * A class file to connect to database
 */
class DB_CONNECT {
    var $myconn;
    // constructor
    // function __construct() {
        // connecting to database
    //     $this->connect();
   //  }

     // destructor
  //  function __destruct() {
        // closing db connection
 //       $this->close();
  //   }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_configmaths.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $this->myconn = $con;

        // returing connection cursor
        return $this->myconn;
    }

    /**
     * Function to close db connection
     a    function close() {
        // closing db connection
        mysqli_close($myconn);
    }

}

?>
```

db_configmaths.php

```html
<?php

/*
 * All database connection variables
 */

define('DB_USER', "***"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', "***"); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', "***"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "****"); // db server
?>
```

JSONPARSER

```html
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Albert on 20/05/2015.
 */
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;

    static JSONObject jObj = null;

    static String json = "";
    // constructor


    public JSONParser() {
    }


    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod


    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // check for request method
            if (method == "POST") {
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } else if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                if (!line.startsWith("<", 0)) {
                    if (!line.startsWith("(", 0)) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                }
            }

            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: The stack trace tells you exactly where and what the exception is - look at that line of code, and log some values or step through with a debugger and find out what is null that shouldn't be.

Comment: @nasch This is null                 Log.d("All Questions: ", json.toString()); which means the json object is null which means there's some problem with the connection since nothing is returned

Comment: So that's what you need to figure out.  I'd start with trying to get the json using a browser, and see what happens.

Comment: @nasch How would I do that?

Comment: Open up a browser and type in the address of the PHP page where the data is supposed to come from.  Press enter.  Look at the screen and see what is returned.

Comment: HTTP 500 error... it's the getallquestions.php file, I have another app which uses the same server and almost the same code with just the query changed and it works perfectly fine... I have no clue what can be wrong here

Comment: Looks like the problem is not with the android app then.  I would delete this question and post a new one about the PHP app since that's where you're getting the error.